# Go API to show swagger api specification (json) in html (Swagger UI)

Tags: go, swagger-2.0

I have go application(gorilla/mux) that serves a specific port. I too have a swagger API specification in the form of json file. Is there any go API that can generate a swagger UI definition from the JSON file just like spring boot.
I am looking at https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger, but i am not able to use this in my go-lang code. It seems this API can be used only from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have your APIs defined in YAML or JSON format, you can use the static 'dist' tree to render it from a browser:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist

Update `index.html` to point to your API doc via this tag:

```
url: "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
```

And if you want to serve this static tree from your go REST-API server, add the following handler:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("dist"))
http.Handle("/swagger/", http.StripPrefix("/swagger/", fs))
```

This will serve the swaggers docs off the `/swagger/` route - reading the content from the `dist` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here as an alternative to using the static `dist` code

SwaggerUI has a `URL` parameter that you can provide your own swagger.json and it will render the UI with your definitions, here is an example:

http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V1

As you can see you don't really need anything other than your own swagger spec and internet access

Comment: But don't get me wrong, there are a lot of advantages of hosting your own swagger-ui, you can customize the UI to your liking, or pin to a specific version to prevent breaking changes from future releases

Answer (score 0):

For cases of self-contained applications (that may need to restrict access to external networks) there is a library that provides Swagger UI as a HTTP handler: https://github.com/swaggest/swgui. You can simply plug it in your router.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/swaggest/swgui/v3"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", v3.NewHandler("My API", "/swagger.json", "/"))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```