# how to serve go-swagger locally?

Tags: go, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a swagger file both in yaml format and json. I can view the yaml file on swaggers online viewer https://editor.swagger.io/ but when I try to serve the file locally I get the error:

`webbrowser: tried to open "http://localhost:40335/docs", no screen found`

After using the command:

`swagger serve -F=swagger swagger.yaml`

To recreate this scenario you can clone this repo: https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/tree/master/fixtures/goparsing/petstore

Then run the following commands (MAC-OS) to generate the yaml file:

*Note: you may have to run these commands in the root of the project using `sudo -s`*

*Instructions for windows installation can be found here https://goswagger.io/install.html*

Download go-swagger

1. `docker pull quay.io/goswagger/swagger`
2. `alias swagger="docker run --rm -it  --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -e GOPATH=$HOME/go:/go -v $HOME:$HOME -w $(pwd) quay.io/goswagger/swagger"`
3. `swagger version` to verify installation

Generate swagger Yaml
4.`swagger generate spec -o ./swagger.yaml --scan-models`

The swagger file should now be generated but for some reason using the command `swagger serve -F=swagger swagger.yaml` gives the error described above.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55550283/1218512

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are running it inside a docker container and there's no browser in it you are getting the `no screen found` error.

This can be fixed by passing the `--no-open` option to `swagger serve ...`.
Also, specify a fixed port by passing the `--port` option.

Source: https://goswagger.io/usage/serve_ui.html